# Mysql - select ids that match all tags

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a cross-reference table:

```
ID | tag
1  | 4
1  | 5
1  | 6
2  | 4
2  | 5
2  | 8
3  | 2
```

I need to select the IDs that match *all* of a set of tags. For example, if I were given the tags `'4','5'` I would get IDs `'1','2'`. If I were given the tags `'4','2'` I would not get any IDs because there were no IDs that matched *all* of the tags.

Also, if I were given the tags `'4','9'` then I also should not get any resulting IDs because a search for `'9'` would result in a `NULL` value, and therefore no IDs match *all* the tags.

I've been pulling my hair out for the last 2 days. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Tags `'4','8'` should give you `ID=2` as result, shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My mistake - let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: See this question too, for more than 10 ways to solve this (common) problem: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The idea of the query is that you need to match the number of records to the number of values you have provided in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
WHERE tag IN (4, 8)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29653/2)

if unique constraint was not specified on tag for every ID, then `DISTINCT` is needed

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
WHERE tag IN (4, 8)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and for maintaining my sanity. That works great! There is a unique constraint on the tags so the first suggestion is perfect.

Comment: My hero! I was ripping my hair out with a 20 lines query, all I was missing was that part, kudos!

Comment: This is one of the slickest queries I've ever seen. You saved me so much heartache from possibly wrestling with nasty unions or sequences of crazy joins!