# SQL Query to list all friends who bought exactly same three items from REF table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to list down all friends who bought exactly ItemID's `1,2,3`

```
CREATE TABLE #FRIENDS
(
    PERSONID int,
    ITEMID int
)

insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (1, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (1, 2)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (1, 3)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (1, 6)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (2, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (3, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (2, 8)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (5, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (4, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (7, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (8, 1)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (8, 2)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (8, 3)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (9, 3)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (9, 2)  
insert into #FRIENDS VALUES (9, 1)
```

sample O/P
PERSONID

```
1  
8  
9
```

I want to get list who bought all the three items NOT any one of the item.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Solutions in this space are usually db-agnostic.  [Answers to this question should work for you too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821345/mysql-select-ids-that-match-all-tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to approach this using `group by` and `having`, because this method is very flexible in terms of the rules for matching the sets.

```
select personid
from #friends f
group by personid
having count(distinct item) = 3 and
       count(distinct (case when item in (1, 2, 3) then item end)) = 3;
```

That is, each person bought three items.  And, each person bought three items in the set you care about.  Voila!  Exactly those three items, no more, no less.

EDIT:

The text says "who brought exactly Item 1,2,3", which is what the above does.  You seem to want person 1, so you want people who bought 1, 2, 3 and perhaps other things.  Easily done:

```
select personid
from #friends f
where item in (1, 2, 3)
group by personid
having count(distinct item) = 3;
```

Comment: I need o/p as below
1  
8  
9

Comment: Thanks Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INTERSECT set operator for this:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9a80/2/0

```
select personid
  from friends
 where itemid = 1
intersect
select personid
  from friends
 where itemid = 2
intersect
select personid
  from friends
 where itemid = 3
```